# Strapi Media Library - Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, strapi

I am trying to have strapi cms upload media to Google Cloud Storage.
I have made the necessary configs but still the files are being uploaded to local storage.
I have made updates to the ./config/middleware.ts file as well.
Is there anything I could be missing?

./config/plugin.ts file

```
    export default {
  upload: {
    provider: "@strapi-community/strapi-provider-upload-google-cloud-storage",
    providerOptions: {
      bucketName: "mybucket",
      publicFiles: true,
      uniform: false,
      basePath: "",
      baseUrl: "https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket",
      serviceAccount: {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "**",
        "private_key_id": "**",
        "private_key": "**",
        "client_email": "**",
        "client_id": "**",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "",
        "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
      },

    },
  },
};
```

./config/middleware.ts

```
export default [
  "strapi::errors",
  "strapi::cors",
  "strapi::poweredBy",
  "strapi::logger",
  "strapi::query",
  "strapi::body",
  "strapi::session",
  "strapi::favicon",
  "strapi::public",
  {
    name: "strapi::security",
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          "connect-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
          "script-src": ["'self'", "https://maps.googleapis.com"],
          "media-src": [
            "'self'",
            "blob:",
            "data:",
            "https://maps.gstatic.com",
            "https://maps.googleapis.com",
            "storage.googleapis.com"
          ],
          "img-src": [
            "'self'",
            "blob:",
            "data:",
            "storage.googleapis.com",
            "https://maps.gstatic.com",
            "https://maps.googleapis.com",
            "khmdb0.google.com",
            "khmdb0.googleapis.com",
            "khmdb1.google.com",
            "khmdb1.googleapis.com",
            "khm.google.com",
            "khm.googleapis.com",
            "khm0.google.com",
            "khm0.googleapis.com",
            "khm1.google.com",
            "khm1.googleapis.com",
            "khms0.google.com",
            "khms0.googleapis.com",
            "khms1.google.com",
            "khms1.googleapis.com",
            "khms2.google.com",
            "khms2.googleapis.com",
            "khms3.google.com",
            "khms3.googleapis.com",
            "streetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com",
            "market-assets.strapi.io",
          ],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
];
```

Someone, please help :)